# How overlap 2 GameObjects and have the top one disappear when an action happens.Unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, overlay, gameobject

I am making a CardGame .I have made is so some GameObjects Spawn on  a click of a button. However I want one of the cards to be overlaid with a CardBack Sprite/Gameobject  which can be removed when an action happens.  I have a sub that creates the GameObjects and gives them a sprite so they are all visible and you can see the Suit,Value...This is the sub.

```
public void PlayerMakeCard(float x, int y, int z)
```

Should i create a new sub specially for the 1 card and what would it be .Unity 2D C#

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Why not use a single GameObject and change its sprite from "CardBack" to the correct card face? This prevents you from creating two GameObjects for each card (one for the back and one for the front).

Comment: Oh yh true ,Thanks for the idea .I will just change the sprite when the action occurs.